c++ std::thread: undefined behavior with capture default
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
        threads.emplace_back([&](){
          std::cout<<"wrong value of i = "<<i<<std::endl;
        });
      }

    for (auto &thread : threads)
      {
        thread.join();
      }

    return 0;
}

In this code, I create a new thread for every loop iteration and print the value of the loop index i. However, the printed values are rubbish, probably undefined behavior.
What is wrong? When I provide [&,i] in the capture list, the code works. But why do I have to capture i by value and not by reference?

Lambdas and capture by reference local variables : Accessing after the scope and What happens if I capture a local variable by reference, and it goes out of scope?

The fact that you asked this question strongly suggests that you have not yet learned what "reference" means. Nothing wrong with that, but maybe you should get a better understanding of the C++ language before you start playing with threads. Threads are tricky.

The problem is that the variable i is valid only inside the loop. Once the loop ends, the life-time of i ends as well, and your lambdas are stuck with an invalid reference.
The natural solution is to capture i by value instead, as you have noticed.

There are also other problems with attempting to capture by reference. One of them is the data-race where the main-thread modifies the value of i while your threads tries to read it without synchronization.
You also have no control over when the threads will run. If you change the scope of the variable i to be local to the function (instead of local to the loop), then it could be that all threads will start after the loop finishes, and the value of i will be equal to 3 in all three threads.

Thanks. A short follow-up. Say I have a variable called double abc and I want that each thread has its own copy of it to modify it individually. Can I create double abc before the loop starts and capture it by value (like with i) or do I have to create double abc within the lambda?

@Simon Its usually a good idea to keep the scope for variables as tight as possible. So define such variables locally inside the lambda. Unless the initial value is coming from an external source (like user input), then it makes more sense to change the scope and capture it by value.

@Someprogrammerdude Why would it make more sense to capture by value if the initial value comes from external source?

@Simon So each thread has its own private copy it can modify. If you capture by reference, then all threads share the same variable, which might not be what you want. And if it is, then you need to add synchronization to avoid data-races.

I understand, yes I want each thread to have its own copy. But the question is whether to define this variable inside the lambda (no capture needed) or outside the lambda (and pass by value). In your first comment, you said capturing by value  makes more sense than defining inside the lambda if the initial value comes from external source. Why?

@Simon Lets say you read input from a user, and that you want that input to be the initial value for all threads. Then store it in a variable, that is either passed as an argument, or captured (by value). If the value isn't coming from an external source (like a file or a user) then the thread function could define it as a local variable and initialize it, there's no need to pass it in from outside.
